# how to rename the variable´s of a column in a single line of code in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame, in the column `state` are the code number of a state,
I want to changes the code number for the real name of the state in a single line of code.

As you can see this method that I use is very long

```
data <- data.frame(state=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 Population=c(4779736,710231,6392017,2915918,37253956))

data$state[data$state==1]<-"Alabama"
data$state[data$state==2]<-"Alaska"
data$state[data$state==3]<- "Arizona"  
data$state[data$state==4]<- "Arkansas "
data$state[data$state==5]<-"California" 
data
```

Comment: Just do `yourvec[data$state]` where `yourvec <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California")`

Answer (score 2):

If the 'state' is `numeric` with sequence values starting from 1, then create a `vector` of state names in the same order as in the index and use the 'state' as index

```
data$state <- v1[data$state]
```

There is also `state.name` which would give all the US states.

```
data$state <- state.name[data$state]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California")
```

Comment: @Jonas It doesn't matter.  `set.seed(24); data <- data.frame(state = sample(1:20, 50, replace = TRUE))`